# How do I do tab completion in Perl's Term::Shell?

Tags: perl, tab-completion

I am using the [Term::Shell](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-Shell) package in Perl for implementing a CLI tool. I am not able to do the tab completion of a command part with that.

comp_CMD() - which is a API provided by this Term::Shell, is to achieve the tab completion. 
This is not helping me. Does anyone know how to make this work??

Sample Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
package Sample;
use base qw(Term::Shell);

sub prompt_str { "Sample\>" };

sub comp_show
{
    my $o = shift;
    my $word = shift;
    $o->completions($word, [qw(all work and no play is no fun at)]);
}

sub run_show
{
        print "run show\n";
}

package main;
Sample->new->cmdloop;
```

This is a run of the program:

```
Sample>show[TAB]
```

The above command doesnt give the expected output.. it just gives me a tab.

Comment: Please post some sample code that you tried to make work.

Comment: Please delete your answer and add the sample code to your question. Please also indent each line of the sample code with 4 additional spaces to make it appear as a block of code.

Comment: @Anandan: I tried to clean up the formatting in your code, but Inshalla is right. Please delete the answer and post the code as part of your question. Use the editing buttons to help you format the code properly as code.

Comment: @Telemachus - you have enough rep to just edit the question, no? Anyway - done now.

Comment: @Marc: I did edit the formatting, but I can't delete the question-posted-as-an-answer, so I asked the OP to do that. (If I _can_ do that, then oops.)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Gnu) or [Term::ReadLine::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Perl) installed.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample works for me. Both "show" and its arguments get completed.

After you type "show", there is nothing more to complete, it's already a full command. To get the first argument to complete, you have to at least provide its first letter; so typing <TAB> immediately after show, can only get you to the place where you have to type the first letter of the argument you want to complete. And if you hit <TAB> twice in a row, you will see what completions are available.

The only thing I found odd is that, if there is only a *single* possible argument to complete, it doesn't automatically get completed. You still have to provide the first letter. It's a little odd that, but perhaps just an oversight by the implementor.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, i am not getting the "add comment" button.. so i am posting as an answer.

I tried this way:

```
sample> sh"TAB"

sample>show w"TAB"
```

Nothing worked.

Does it have anything to do with environment? or something else?